# AFNetworking building a URL for GET with parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have a few paramaters I want to pass to the URL when performing a GET

The method I use for building the URL is:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: baseURL];

NSString* url = @"http://pretendurl.com/something";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod: @"GET"
                                                        path: url
                                                  parameters: params];
```

Where params is an nsdictionary that has been populated.

This adds the parameters to the url file but it adds &format=json to the end of the URL.

I would like to know how to get it to build the URL without the last piece. I had a look through the AFNetworking source code but couldn't spot where it actually adds that bit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you could convert you dictionary params to query url using a function like this

```
-(NSString*) getQueryUrlFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*) dict usingUrlEncoder:(BOOL)makeUrlEncoded
{
    if (dict == nil)
        return @"";

    NSMutableString* outputStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    int px = 0;
    for (NSString* key in dict) {

        NSString* param = (NSString*) [dict objectForKey:key];
        // using urlEncoding : look for NSString+URLEncoding.h implementation
        if (makeUrlEncoded)
            param = [param urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [outputStr appendFormat:@"%@=%@",key,param];
        if ( px < ([dict count]-1 ) )
            [outputStr appendString:@"&"];

        px++;
    }

    return outputStr;
}
```

So ...

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                  requestWithURL: baseURL
                                  cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData 
                                  timeoutInterval: 60.f];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];


NSString* paramString = [self getQueryUrlFromDictionary:params usingUrlEncoder:YES];

NSData *postData = [paramString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

I use something like this and works fine, hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

for me everything should work fine, but try this:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"http://pretendurl.com"]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                                path:@"something"
                                                          parameters:params];
```

Comment: I can't see how that's different to what is done in the question. Am I missing something?